# Send Array List through Query Parameters on HTTP Request and IN operator-Mule 4

Tags: mule, mule4

I am sending array list of Query params through HTTP request
Array list id's `[1234,3442,9489,9498]`

```
    <http:request method="GET" config-ref="HTTP_Request_configuration" 
     path="${p.path}">
    <http:query-params><![CDATA[#[output application/java
    ---    {"id" : payload  }]]]>
   </http:query-params>
```

I am getting following error:

> Error: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to > java.lang.String

Note: if i send them through for each, its working as expected. But i would like to pass them as list through  query string params using `IN` operator in database

select Query:

```
   <flow name="query database"  > 
<set-variable value="#[attributes.queryParams.'id']" doc:name="ID"   variableName="ID"/>
<db:select doc:name="Get data"  config-ref="Db Connection">
  <db:sql >
   SELECT * from Mytable where id in ( :Ref) </db:sql>
                <db:input-parameters ><![CDATA[#[{
                    Ref: vars.ID
                }]]]></db:input-parameters>

    </db:select>
```

Workaround: Array list is converted to `1234,3442,9489,9498`  using dataweave function `reduce($+$$)`, yet returning error

Any ideas on how to pass array list with coma seperated values through query params and using them in `IN` clause of DB query

> Edit: (payload joinBy ", ") as String helped me pass these values as
>   string, Also changed type in RAML.

Now, how can i pass these values to DB to `IN` clause

Answer (score 1):

True you cannot pass an ArrayList as part of the query string as is. You will need to convert to comma-separated or similar to pass as part of the query string, just like you are doing with dataweave.

To use them as part of an IN query with expects an ArrayList you will need to convert he comma-separted list back to an ArrayList.

You can do this in Dataweave using `splitBy` function:

```
#[attributes.queryParams.'id' splitBy(",")]
```

Also noticed you are setting variable `vPersonRef` but referring to it as `vars.ID` `doc:name` is jsut for documentation. So you need to refer to it using the `name` attribute. so `vars.vPersonRef` not `vars.ID`(or rename it):

```
 <set-variable value="#[attributes.queryParams.'id']" doc:name="ID"   variableName="vPersonref"/>
...
vars.ID
```

Comment: Appreciate for this reponse, i have achieved this by changing type in RAML definition, further select statement is returning empty values by applying filter clause. These are int values with coma seperated